# Update FAQ - Fitness / Nutrition is just Fitness

Tags: bug, site-faq

skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq

This is outdated.  Fitness and Nutrition is now just Fitness.

As an aside, go yell at them, since this is a poor decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. (The editing part, not the yelling part.)

Updated to "Physical Fitness" as per their site name.

Thanks.